# Is there a built-in Angular lostfocus event?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, custom-directive

So I went ahead and implemented a custom directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'input[applostfocus]' })
export class LostFocus {
    @Output()
    applostfocus = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target' ])
    focusout(input) {
        this.applostfocus.emit(input);
    }
}
```

It listens to the `onfocusout` [DOM Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp), and emits an event.

If it is included in the module, it can be used like this:

```
<input type="number" (applostfocus)="numberLostfocus($event)"></input>

public numberLostfocus($event) {
    console.log("applostfocus");
}
```

---

However my question is: **can It really be, that a `@Directive` like this does not exist in Angular 7?**

I've searched the web and there were only solutions for AngularJS. Also I've been looking at the [official docs](https://v7.angular.io/docs). The reason why I'm asking, is because this feels slightly overengineered and unnatural to do with such an advanced framework.

For instance, you wouldn't have to make a custom directive to listen on a click event:

```
<button type="button" (click)="somemethod()"></button>
```

I wrote this question to make sure I'm doing it right, and that I'm not reinventing the wheel. I'd expect answers like:

- Yes, You're doing It right, there is no such thing as because: ...
- No, You were missing ...

#### Edit:

It's actually documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#on-blur).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `(blur)="numberLostfocus($event)"` for the same purpose. It's built-in.

Comment: Yep that's It.. please kill me ^^ I wonder how I didn't find this. But its [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#on-blur)

Comment: They're not quite the same, e.g. [*"`focusout` bubbles whole `blur` does not"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event).

Comment: @jonrsharpe so you're saying, that I could do `<div (applostfocus)="numberLostfocus($event)"><input type="number" ></input></div>` and it would still trigger it?

Comment: @LuckyLikey no, that's not what I'm saying (it's also not true, as your directive is specific to `input` elements); I'm saying that `blur` and `focusout` are not quite the same event. You can bind to `focusout` using, inevitably, `(focusout)="..."`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but what's meant by _bubbles whole_? Is it similar to `WPF`s `RoutingStrategy.Bubble`? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routingstrategy?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @LuckyLikey see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture. *"Whole"* was a typo, sorry; the linked article says *while*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so this basically means that the focusout event first runs through the capture phase then the bubble phase, while blur skips it.